# NSWindow shrink to fit content with padding

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm new to cocoa development and wondering what the right approach would be to the following:

I have a window with controls who's size is dynamic. In other words, I don't know the width of the window in advance. I also want to give the window a padding of 15px. In the CSS world I would simply pad a div and make it inline to accomplish this. I can't seem to figure out how to do this with NSWindow/NSView.

Comment: Use auto layout?

Comment: But how using auto layout? I've tried a bunch of ways. Set the constraints of all the child views and set the width of the main view to 1 with a low priority and the width of the view is 1. That is, the children aren't forcing it to expand to fit them.

Comment: Well, you gave no details. Your question is vague and completely open ended. But the macOS equivalent of CSS is auto layout. Now you know what to learn about.

Comment: I realize that's the technology. I'm asking for techniques. E.g. use a outer and inner NSView with margins, use an NSStackView, don't use nested views and make sure all the controls have the correct margin constraints, etc.

Comment: But you are the one who gives no details. “give the window a padding of 15px” is meaningless. Pad what?

Answer (score 0):

Question is too vague to be sure, but IFF I'm understanding you, you want a subview of the window to resize itself to always be 15pixels from the left and right sides of the enclosing window (for example).

here are the two constraints (as set up in Interface Builder, but you can do the same thing from code):

[image: Leading space to superview]
[image]

That's one view whose width is set to adjust while keeping the left and right padding to the window frame at 15 pixels (points actually, but don't worry about that).

As your view hierarchy gets more complicated you'll use different techniques for different pieces of the layout.  Which is why matt was suggesting that you haven't been specific enough to actually answer a question.  (What specific part of what you are you trying to do isn't working and what did you try that didn't work?).  I've shown you the first step of the simplest outer layer above and it reflects a principle that carries down through your view hierarchy, but there are other cases - two items with the same width, three items with the same horizontal space between them, and so on - that require different techniques.

It sounds reading the auto layout documentation all the way through would be helpful for you.  It talks about different types of relations (Equal is what I used below) and some on techniques.  Unfortunately Apple's documentation situation is a bit of a mess at the moment which makes this more difficult than it should be (sigh).

What used to be the definitive [auto layout guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1) is "unmaintained" and the place that documentation seems to be heading is incomplete and certainly less accessible.  The most useful part for this context is the [NSLayoutContraint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint) documentation, though that links to the "Unmaintained" document noted above (sigh).

Comment: I've filed a bug with apple against the documentation flaws revealed by looking for the right links to share with you as part of answering this question.